# Primefaces BarChart giving exceptions

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am migrating to primefaces 12 and jakarta ee 10 and with the barChart, I am facing a number of problems. I saw that the CartesianChartModel is no longer supported, so I changed my java code to BarChartModel. However, when I use `<p:chart type="bar" id="actReqChart" model="#{barModel.model}">` , I get an exception saying -

*Cannot convert [org.primefaces.model.charts.bar.BarChartModel@4970dead] of type [class org.primefaces.model.charts.bar.BarChartModel] to [class org.primefaces.model.chart.ChartModel]*

If I change p:chart type="bar" to p:barChart, I get -
*Cannot invoke "org.primefaces.model.charts.ChartModel.getData()" because "model" is null*

Really confused here as to what to do.

Comment: Migrate to the new chart.js model. See the migration guides.

Comment: @JasperdeVries can you give me a more detailed answer please? I dont understand the migration guide as to what exactly is to be done.

Comment: You can find an example in the [showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chartjs/bar/bar.xhtml) and in the [documentation](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/components/charts?id=barchart)